# Combining Two Machine Learning algorithms to achieve greater accuracy in predictions

Tags: scikit-learn

I have been working on a project where many classification algo are used, most are giving satisfactory results except Gaussian Naive Bayes whos accuracy is close to 48%. I intend to combine SVM and Gaussian Naive Bayes together in an algorithm to achieve greater accuracy but can't find a way to do so.
If anyone could please help me out with this ?

Comment: You might want to look at [Voting classifier](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/ensemble.html#voting-classifier).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to investigate the literature about "ensemble learning".

Ensemble learning is the area of machine learning were multiple classifiers (experts) are used to generate (with a voting approach) the final decision.

To increase the stability of your model I would like to suggest to use several instances of your "best" classifiers trained on different versions of your original training set (bagging/bootstrap aggregation).

As additional remark. If the support vector machine is giving significantly better results than the Naive Bayes, it could be the case that the samples are not well separable in the original feature space whereas moving in higher dimension (depending on the kernel of the SVM) you achieve a better separation. You could choose to design better features or to increase the number of features to achieve better results with Naive Bayes.